# NullPointerException but don't understand why

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` which is supposed to display a `VideoView` and some `TextViews`. However, `VideoView` is null, along with other controls, even though the layout has been inflated.

Here is the code where I retrieve the pointer to various controls:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    controls = new MediaController(getActivity());

    title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
    date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
    description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
    video = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video);

    controls.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(controls);
}
```

But, debugger says otherwise:
[image]

Why are they null?
I have inflated the layout in create view where they are defined.

StackTrace:

```
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.example.tqafragments.VideoDialog.showNewVideo(VideoDialog.java:61)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.example.tqafragments.MainActivity.feedItemSelected(MainActivity.java:36)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.example.tqafragments.FeedFragment$2.onItemClick(FeedFragment.java:73)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-04 06:19:07.804: E/AndroidRuntime(1758):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

ShowNewVideo:

```
public void showNewVideo(Feed f){
                title.setText(f.getTitle());
                date.setText(f.getDate());
                description.setText(Html.fromHtml(f.getDescription()));
                video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(f.getVideoURL())); // Line 61
                video.start();
        }
```

Comment: What appears in logcat?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would show the error log

Comment: The problem may be in getActivity() method. Try replacing it with the activity instance.

Comment: @PaulRenton posted error log

Comment: @AmeerMoaaviah I tried `MainActivity.this` but Eclipse says that it is out of scope.

Comment: `showNewVideo()` is simply supposed to populate these controls with data. SetText, etc The `Feed` item which contains the data is not null. I debugged that

Comment: Show the code of `showNewVideo()` and tell us which line is line 61. Also...when are you calling `showNewVideo()`?

Comment: It seems like the `VideoDialog` never gets inflated.

Comment: @LittleChild : I edited my comment (sorry). When does `showNewVideo()` get called? It seems it might be happening before the `Fragment` has been properly created.

Comment: @Squonk It gets called in a callback handler method in `MainActivity` whenever the user clicks on a list. Callback handler works properly cause this same app runs properly on tablets (where no VideoDialog) is involved. In small screens, I need to show a dialog. This is when NPE occurs :)

Comment: If `title`, `date`, `description` and `video` are all `null` at the end of `onViewCreated(View, Bundle)`, then why doesn't `video.setMediaController(controls);` throw NPE?

Comment: @vikram `controls` is also null.

Comment: @LittleChild : Are you sure the `VideoView` ( `video` in your `onViewCreated()` ) method is actually null? You don't show that in the screenshot.

Comment: NVM, I figured it out. Golden rule: **Never try to modify a DialogFragment using your own method. Use Intent and Bundle in onCreateView**

Answer (score 0):

you need to some change

put your code

```
title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);
description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
video = (VideoView) view.findViewById(R.id.video);
```

from onViewCreated() to onCreateView() then bind data on onViewCreated() method.